# String constant reference as value of Annotation attribute causes compile error

Tags: grails, groovy, annotations, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I am using my properties file to get the values for `@Scheduled` annotation attributes.I am able to get the values from properties file but when I tries to pass String constant reference to Annotation attribute  then compile time exception is raised.

```
@Slf4j
@CompileStatic
class TestJobService {
    static lazyInit = false
    public static String jobInterval = getSomePropertiesFileValues?.fixedRateInMS instanceof String? getSomePropertiesFileValues.fixedRateInMS:'10000'
    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = TestJobService.jobInterval)
    void executeEveryTenSeconds() {
        def date = new Date()
        println date.format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST'))
    }

}
```

> Attribute 'fixedDelayString' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but
> found type 'java.lang.Object' in
> @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled

Then I tried to use String to pass like:

```
@Slf4j
@CompileStatic
class TestJobService {
    static lazyInit = false
    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = '${getSomePropertiesFileValues.fixedRateInMS}')
    void executeEveryTenSeconds() {
        def date = new Date()
        println date.format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST'))
    }
}
```

OR

```
public static final String jobInterval = getSomePropertiesFileValues?.fixedRateInMS instanceof String? getSomePropertiesFileValues.fixedRateInMS:'10000'
```

prevents the variable from being treated as an inline constant and compiler complains of not being inline constant.

I understand that using single quote `'${getSomePropertiesFileValues.fixedRateInMS}'`we can get compiler to know that I want GString behaviour. But I don't know is this a bug in Groovy or its a functionality which I need to implement in some other way to pass the string values as annotation attributes. Any lead or any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: `"I understand that using single quote '${getSomePropertiesFileValues.fixedRateInMS}'we can get compiler to know that I want GString behaviour."` - I do not think that is correct.  Our compiler extensions do not have support for GString expressions.  You can only put property placeholders inside of the curly braces.

Comment: Jeff fixedRateInMS is a property placeholders from configuration.groovy file, is it possible to pass a attribute from properties file like spring annotation supports?

Comment: `" is it possible to pass a attribute from properties file like spring annotation supports"` - yes.  Your code sample shows that, but that is a different thing that GString behavior.  With GString behavior you can put any valid Groovy code inside of the curly braces.

Comment: We don't support GString expressions or SPeL, but you can use property placeholders which get replaced with config values.